# if a query has two update statements what will ExecuteNonQuery() return?

Tags: sql, ado.net, executenonquery

if a query has two update statements what executenonquery will return? Will it club the row count affected in both the update statements OR will return the count updated in last statement?

Comment: I think it is easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

It return summary of total row affected of all statement.
For example, if first statement result is 3 row affected and second statement is 12 row affected, then the return value would be 15